# Does settimeout change gobal variabe?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let na = 'ye';
setTimeout(()=>{
     na='lin'
},2000)
```

Hello guys let me ask something. First of all declare a varible na = "ye"
and in settimeout I change na = "lin". In facts my variable should change after 2 seconds agree?

```
let a = 1;
while(a==1){
    console.log(na); 
    if(na=='lin'){
        a =2;
        console.log(na);
        break;
    } 
}
```

I add it  a loop and start printing "na" and I think after 2 seconds its should start printing "lin" but its dont

Comment: The loop blocks the thread, and no timers will be fired until the thread is free.

Comment: Please improve your question, your grammar is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a single thread asynchronous language.

Hence your while loop is blocking the settimeout from being executed.

Also by this you can infer, that settimeout is only a best effort function to induce a delay in your code.

Comment: "*JavaScript is a single thread asynchronous language.*" it's neither of these things. The language doesn't have "threads" but neither is it constrained to single thread. Parallel execution is an opt-in, so most code will still run in the same thread, though. Also, the language is not "asynchronous" - there are *plenty* of synchronous execution involved. There are *some* asynchronous parts. But it does not make sense to say the entire language is "asynchronous". Many languages do have asynchronous tasks of some form.

Comment: @VLAZ by default it is. You could make things synchronous by using promises… etc, but by default it is async

Comment: @VLAZ my bad should not have said single thread, but it does run that way, by default. 
When you have to do some sort of extra work to do something it becomes obvious that it is not the fundamental idea of a language, it is just a attempt at bringing some sort of parity with languages in the wild.

Comment: `a = 1; b = 2; c = a + b;` will only ever run synchronously and it always has. Promises are not needed to ensure sequential operation. So, no - by default JavaScript operates synchronously.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).